# Anyway to forbid deleting my changes made in Form1.Designer.cs if i edit form via Form Designer in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, express, windows-forms-designer

This is sad issue...
I added to there a lot of checks like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Profiles");
```

Replaced with:

```
#if DEMO
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Lines");
#else
   System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Profiles");
#endif
```

But once I added event handler to one of form events, all my checks gone -_-
What can i do to make keep those but be able to change form via designer?
I use VC# Express 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the `.designer.cs` file is that it gets regenerated *every time* you make designer changes.

As you have seen, generated files should not be edited, because they get regenerated and any changes you have made will be lost.

Make these changes in the class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying code in the designer. In order to be able to generate a preview it is forbidden to write any code with cyclomatic complexity higher than 1 in the automatically genereated section. This means no if, loop, or method calls.

Instead you should make these changes elsewhere, after the InitializeComponents()!
When filling an array with control elements (for easy access to them later on) I usually make a separate method InitializeDynamic().

Note: you can change the code in the designer section, just only ones that can be directly adapted in the design (and you could therefore have done in the designer itself).

Answer (score 1):

No, The Desinger files are for the VS designer and will be regenerated at will...

You can achieve what you want by adding code to the class constructor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        #if DEMO
           var changeNodes = treeView1.Nodes.Find("Profiles", true);
           if (changeNodes.Length>0)
           {
               foreach(TreeNode node in changeNodes)
               {
                    node.Name = "Lines";
                    node.Text = "Lines text";
                    // add/set whatever else you need in demo mode
               }
           }
           // or remove all nodes and add new ones
        #endif 
    }
```

Comment: err, that treeNode1 is invisible in form constructor